# I'm trying to get data from database from php file

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and cant figure out a way to grab data from the database.
I have set up a new php file. 
I am using code from theme pages to get it the same way on the new file.php

```
<?php
global $post;
$id=$_GET['id'];
$dt_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fields', true);
print_r($dt_fields);
?>
```

so I am getting the id from the url and trying to retrieve details from the db I know I need to include some things to get this working but I really cant find what.

The error I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_post_meta()

Comment: PHP does not have any function called get_post_meta(). Maybe you have to include a file which defines this function?

Comment: you need to include wp-load in your script. : require_once("/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");

Comment: You can also do it in Function.php

Comment: If your new php file outside of wordpress environment you need to include that file ( wp-load )